# Changing the DataFrame in a complex way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
id|s1|s2|s3|s4|s5
0|a|b|NaN|NaN|NaN
0|NaN|NaN|NaN|c|NaN
0|a1|NaN|NaN|c2|NaN
1|b|c|NaN|NaN|NaN
1|NaN|NaN|a1|NaN|NaN
1|a1|b|NaN|c1|NaN
.
.
.
.
1000(rows)...............
```

I want this to be restructured like this:

```
id|s1|s2|s3|s4|s5
0|a|b|NaN|c|NaN
0|a1|b|NaN|c2|NaN
1|b|c|a1|c1|NaN
1|a1|b|a1|c1|NaN
```

I have tried:

```
df.unstack(),df.melt() and df.pivot()
```

None of them gave me the expected result.Basically I want to reduce the NaN as much as possible. Could anyone suggest me a way? I want only one entry per cell not a group of entries in single cell.
I dont want NaN values but I want flows as mentioned in the first output.I want NaN only when there exists no values in any of the rows in same id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group on `id` and `ffill+bfill` each row , then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

---

```
   id  s1 s2   s3  s4  s5
0   0   a  b  NaN   c NaN
2   0  a1  b  NaN  c2 NaN
3   1   b  c   a1  c1 NaN
5   1  a1  b   a1  c1 NaN
```

Comment: I see that s5 is missing

Comment: @SriTest yeah, I missed them to add in the input. Added now.

Comment: but I am getting some values as NaN even if the value exists in the some other row of same id.I dont want any cell to be NaN if some value exists in the column of corresponding id.Otherwise it can be NaN

Comment: @SriTest can you add an example in the question? This answer works fine in this example and should work

Comment: Please take a look at my comment and question @anky_91

Comment: @SriTest didnt get you i am getting the output as `expected, check if the `None` is a string or actual `None`, we need a more clear example v/s expected output showing why this code doesnot work

Comment: Hey actually it worked.I applied on a wrong df.sorry for the confusion.